# Determine the day someone turns 21

Tags: vb.net

I need to determine the day of week that someone turns 21. I have tried so many different ways to do this, I can get the age, the day of week a person was born but not the day they turned 21, this is my current code. Yes this is homework but I have worked a few hours on this and can't figure it out,

```
Private Sub btnDetermine_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDetermine.Click
    Dim dob As Date = txtDay.Text
    Dim age, days As Double
    days = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dob, Today) / 365
    age = Fix(days)
    txtWeek.Text = age.DayOfWeek.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at  `DateTime.AddYears()` just add 21 to the DOB (using a proper DateTime variable of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, think of how you would solve this problem in real life, then try to write a program that would go about it in the same manner.

So, first of all, I would find out what day is the subject's 21st birthday by simply adding 21 years to his/her date of birth. This is really simple in Visual Basic because of the `AddYears` function.

```
Dim _21BirthDay = dob.AddYears(21)
```

Then, I would look at a calendar and find out what day of the week that was.

```
Dim WeekDayOf_21BirthDay = _21BirthDay.DayOfWeek
```

Then, I could use the `WeekDayOf_21BirthDay` variable to show the user.